# Access 2016 - Command Button Wizard will not appear

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-office-2016

I am on windows 10 with office 2016. I am following along with [this tutorial](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/access2013/17) and running into an issue.

The text describes the third step of the method as placing the button from *Form Layout View* (step 1). There is no *form layout view*, there are *form view* and *layout view*. *form view* has no design tab, so we can't place a button. That leads me to think "it must be layout view".

When you place the button, step 4 says the **Command Button Wizard** will appear. It does not appear. Looking at the dropdown for the options for the controls on the right, I see *Use Control Wizards*  is selected (it is darkened). The button places just fine, but no dialog appears.

This led me to believe that maybe a different view is appropriate. There are only 3 views listed and I've already explored 2. So I looked at *Design View* next. It also shows the *use control wizards* option as selected, but placing the button does not produce the wizard.

I went on to read about how to set up a button without the wizard. It says that you can change the values of the properties: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-command-button-to-start-an-action-or-a-series-of-actions-c7bf2827-2f3e-42b8-83d6-6c4f0de78990#bmfromscratch (see step 7)

However, in my experience, the properties are listed (on the right), but not their values. double clicking or otherwise trying to set a value for a field, for example Name, does not work. Is there a some setup we need to do with a database before these things work properly?

***edit*** - I found a part of my problem, the property sheet on the right was too narrow to show the values. dragging it out I see the key-value pairs for each property of the object I am inspecting on the form. I still don't know how to use this to set up a new record, but, at least I am getting somewhere.

Finally, I started to build event, hoping I could do it that way. That brings up VisualBasic. The left panel there has properties for the button, both the property keys and their values. It is editable (!!).

This is where I get confused. What should I do to make a new record? I don't see how to do this using properties, I'm not sure how the wizard works for this action.

If I write the VB code like:

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub New_Record_Click()
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Order items] ([Order ID], [Menu Item ID], [Quantity ID]) VALUES (Me.Text43.Value, Me.Combo16.Value, Me.Quantity.Value)"
End Sub
```

It appears to do nothing when I click that button in form view: I don't see the a new record when I change some fields and do this.

*• **edit**: I found that somehow I had `New_Record_Click`, probably from an earlier attempt at the button, and that was the reason. from there I was able to debug the script. It still prompts that you are about the add a row, though (probably a good thing really). This produces a solution but does not debug the wizard. I could still use help. Here's the working code:*

```
Private Sub NewRecord_Click()

    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Order items] ([Order ID], [Menu Item ID], [Quantity]) VALUES (" & Me.Text43.Value & ", " & Me.Combo16.Value & ", " & Me.Quantity.Value & ")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that you're trying to add a control on a subform (while inside the main form) using the Control Wizard. That does not work.

Instead you should open the subform in another window and add the control there. That way the Control Wizard will pop up.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Access 2016 on Windows 10. After much research, I found my answer.

Try this: At the top of your ribbon type in the "Tell me what you want to do..." box that should be all the way to the right. Then type, "wizard". A "controls" option should be the first in the drop down under it. Go to the arrow to the right (click the controls) and select "Use Control Wizard" and that should turn on the wizard when using buttons etc...

I hope this helps.

Comment: I just want to be clear - you are saying that the control "Use Control Wizards" that is on the ribbon, even when that does not work, turning it on through the help search still works?

Comment: I found that my control wizard was off, so turning it on this way worked for me. Is it not working for you still after following these directions?

Answer (score 0):

LJJW is correct. If you did everything mentioned above such as checking that your wizard is turned on in the dropdown menu of controls (darkened state) then the only way to fix it is to go to "Design View" then add the button. The Wizard will start then. Strange but it is a fix. It could be an issue due to the old version of Office or Access files still in the registry BUT instead of going through all that, just do the Design view way and go back to get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't post an answer to confirm that another answer worked.  The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question, and each answer should contribute another solution.  The way to indicate that an answer was useful is to invest a little time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://superuser.com/help/privileges) to upvote answers you like.

Answer (score 0):

Finally tricked Access into getting around this bug! Add a dummy button with the control wizard off. Then turn control wizard back on and add the button you want. It works for me. Delete the dummy button...

Answer (score 0):

1 - go to Controls pattel and chose the option use controls wizards.
2 - and than drag the button on the form , button wizard will open.

**Regards,
Vineet SHarma**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I've been researching for about an hour now and have read multiple times that you should turn on the "use control wizards" option but I already had. For some reason, I had to go into Design View for the Wizard to pop up. In the Layout View, the Wizard just wouldn't pop up. Hope this works for some other people that had the same problem.